# IOS Change between UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, global-variables, transition

I use the next code to transition into UIViewControllers but exist delay in transition:

```
VCSettings *viewNew = [[VCSettings alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewNew.globalValues = globalValues;
UIViewController *presentingVC = self.presentingViewController;
[presentingVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{[presentingVC presentViewController: viewNew animated:NO completion:nil];
```

What is the problem?

Cumps

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "but exist delay in transition"? Maybe illustrate it with a video?

Comment: The problem is I pressed button to move second UIViewController and the transition views appear the viewcontroller as it is in xcode and then change the values.

Comment: Call it slow in transition!